# QMutex: destroying locked mutex in Qt thread

Tags: c++, qt

I'm facing an issue with my Qt application involving threads and QMutex. I have a QThread subclass that runs a loop, and I'm using a QMutex to handle thread synchronization. However, I keep getting the error message "QMutex: destroying locked mutex" in the console.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```cpp
// mythread.h
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread();
    void run();
    bool Stop ;

signals:
    void NumberChanged(int);
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

```cpp
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>
MyThread::MyThread() {}


void MyThread::run(){
    for(int i = 0; i<10000;i++){

        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();
        if (this->Stop) {break;}
        mutex.unlock();

        emit NumberChanged(i);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I'm encountering the "QMutex: destroying locked mutex" error. I've tried different approaches based on online suggestions, but the problem persists.

Can someone please help me identify the issue and suggest a solution? I appreciate any insights or guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Why is your mutex local to the loop body?

Answer (score 9):

Manually locking and unlocking a mutex is generally a bad idea. If you leave the loop via `if (this->Stop) {break;}` then the mutex will not be unlocked. If something between the call to `lock` and `unlock` throws an exception, the mutex will not be unlocked.

Rather than manually locking and unlocking you should make use of a RAII lock. Qt offers [`QMutexLocker`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmutexlocker.html) to do that:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10000;i++){
    {
        QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
        if (this->Stop) {break;}
    }
    emit NumberChanged(i);
}
```

The `QMutexLocker` acquires the lock on the mutex when constructed and frees the mutex (aka unlocks it) when it is destroyed. This is the basic and simple yet powerful principle of RAII (resource allocation is initialization): Resources are acquired on construction and freed on destruction. No matter how and why `lock` is destroyed (exception, breaking the loop, etc...) it will unlock the mutex.

Note that I didnt check the logic of your code. The above is the equivalent to your code and the only change is that if the loop is left via `break` the mutex is unlocked.